# Linear layout (percentage definition - layout_weight) Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

**1. Question**

I would like to have a full screen linear layout with 2 lines, while the first line is divided into 2 sections, where one section occupies 30% and second 70% of the width and the second line is divided into 2 sections of the same size (each 50% of the width). Additionally the first line occupy only 33% of the screen height.

I think use of the **android:layout_weight** is the proper way. But it is little tricky as sometimes it applies to **android:layout_width** and sometimes to **android:layout_height** attribute and it applies to one or either depending on the values of respective XML attributes.

After experimenting I have found that if I set the attribute value to **wrap_content** it is overriden by **android:layout_weight** setting, e.g. following code applies the **android:layout_weight** to **android:layout_width**:

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="#FF0000"/>
```

Is this a correct approach?

**2. Example**

In order to demeaned layout (see image) I have to do this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#FF0000"/> 
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:background="#00FF00"/> 
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#0000FF"/> 
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#0000AA"/>      
  </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Thanks
STeN

Answer (score 1):

```
< LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#FF0000"/> 
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:background="#00FF00"/> 
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#0000FF"/> 
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#0000AA"/>      
  </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```